# Why does the output of float contain more zeroes compared to its size in c

Tags: c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a = 1.5;
    printf("%f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The displayed output is `1.500000`. Why does it contain 5 zeroes?

Comment: Because that is simply the default precision for `%f` to print out a `float`.  You can tell `printf()` explicitly how many decimal places you want, if you want different behavior. Read the documentation for `printf()` for details.

Comment: `a` is saving the best _value_, not the text.

Comment: @chux: Huh? The best value of `a` is 17, not 1.5. Everybody knows 17 is superior to 1.5. `a` is just storing the exactly the value that was assigned, nothing better or worse.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, I think chux means the closest possible value. (e.g., 1/10 is stored as 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101 (binary), which isn't exactly 1/10)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Congratulations on 100k.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Thanks. It did not come with a prize, though. I expected some sort of foofaraw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubles (and floats) have six-digit precision (after the decimal point) when printing by default.

From the printf(3) man page:

> The  double  argument  is  rounded  and converted to decimal notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where **the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.  If the precision is
>                 missing, it is taken as 6**; if the precision is explicitly zero, no decimal-point character appears.  If a decimal point appears, at least one digit appears before it.